# Gatsby and Webpack Error in function Document.createElement

Tags: gatsby

I'm struggling with a strange issue, which root cause is still unknown for me.

I've got problem with a single programatically generate webpage in gatsby. Everything goes fine after:

`gatsby clean`

For a single run. At a second there are some strange problems with:
`Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/static/blog-3923f8d90999bace0db9cf5ca30f1dc4.jpg') is not a valid name.`

in `gatsby develop` mode, with `gatsby build` the issue looks like that:

```
 ERROR  UNKNOWN

Truncated page data information for the failed page "/pl/blog/": {
  "errors": {},
  "path": "/pl/blog/",
  "slicesMap": {},
  "pageContext": {
    "name": "blog",
    "lang": "pl"
  }
}

failed Building static HTML for pages - 8.497s

 ERROR #95313  HTML.COMPILATION

Building static HTML failed for path "/pl/blog/"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  23 |  * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL GREGOR AISCH OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT,
  24 |  * INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
> 25 |  * BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
     |                                                                     ^
  26 |  * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY
  27 |  * OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
  28 |  * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE,


  WebpackError: Invalid tag: /static/blog-3923f8d90999bace0db9cf5ca30f1dc4.jpg
```

How can I debug this issue? What the heck is going on? The problem is related to this single subpage on a second run.